# ERROR: operator does not exist : time without time zone >= bytea

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I get error like this

```
ERROR: operator does not exist : time without time zone >= bytea 
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

when i try the following sql in java hibernate

```
select sto.name AS store, 
       sum(odi.subtotal_price) AS sales, sum(odi.qty) AS qty_sold,
       ((sum(odi.subtotal_price))/(sum(odi.qty))) AS average, 
       min(CAST(ord.date_out AS date)) AS start_date,
       max(CAST(ord.date_out AS date)) AS end_date,
       concat(min(CAST(ord.date_out AS time)), ' - ', max(CAST(ord.date_out AS time))) as time,
       sum(odi.cost_of_good_sold*odi.qty) AS COGS, ((sum(odi.cost_of_good_sold*odi.qty))/(sum(odi.qty))) AS average_cogs,
       date_trunc('day', ord.date_out) AS trx_day
FROM trx_order_detail_item odi
LEFT JOIN trx_order AS ord on ord.id = odi.order_id
LEFT JOIN mst_store AS sto on sto.id = ord.store_id
WHERE sto.id = :store and ord.date_out between :date1 and :date2 
      and CAST(ord.date_out AS TIME) BETWEEN :hour1 AND :hour2 and ord.order_status_id IN :orderstatus and ord.void_status = :voidStatus
GROUP BY sto.name, date_trunc('day', ord.date_out)
ORDER BY date_trunc('day', ord.date_out)
```

the error exist in `CAST(ord.date_out AS TIME) BETWEEN :hour1 AND :hour2`
before i added that it runs perfectly
any suggestion for this?

Comment: Obviously `:hour1` is of type `bytea`. That won't work. Use a different data type!

Comment: thanks for your advice, i fixed it by using `BETWEEN CAST(:hour1 AS TIME) AND CAST(:hour2 AS TIME)`